# how to print list with new elements

Tags: python

I'm trying to print  list of keywords on html page through flask which is updated newly present in doc file .But it appends to existing list while printing .I tried with clearing each time while it takes new file but no use.how do i fix it

```
def find_sentences(paragraph):
global ref_data_lists,ref_lists,sentences,ref_data_list,ref_list
end = True
# sentences = []
while end > -1:
    end = find_sentence_end(paragraph)
    if end > -1:
        sentences.append(paragraph[end:].strip())
        paragraph = paragraph[:end]
sentences.append(paragraph)
sentences.reverse()
ref_list.clear()
ref_data_list.clear()
for sentence in sentences:
    # sentence=re.sub(r'^(\[\d+\])', '', sentence)
    ref = re.search(r'^\[\d+\]', sentence, re.MULTILINE)
    ref_data = re.search(r'(\[\d+\]\s*){1,}', sentence)

    if ref:

        print(ref_list)
        ref_list.append(sentence)
    ref_lists = '\n------------------\n'.join(ref_list)

    if ref_data:


        print(ref_data_list)
        ref_data_list.append(sentence)
    ref_data_lists = '\n------------------\n'.join(ref_data_list)

print(ref_list)
print(ref_data_list)
# for refs in ref_list:
#   for ref_data in ref_data_list:
#      r=refs[:3]
#     if r in ref_data:
#        print(refs,"------------>",ref_data)

return
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert the reset into the loop such like:

```
for sentence in sentences:
    ref_list.clear()
    ref_data_list.clear()
```

instead

```
ref_list.clear()
ref_data_list.clear()
for sentence in sentences:
```

Comment: :: Hi @AKSHATHAV if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.